# Python: Assigning an initial numpy array to another variable, changing few elements of the new variable changes the initial numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to do calculations on an intial 3x3 array (say 'x') which I would need again later for further calculations. So, I have another variable ('y') to make a copy of 'x' (y = x), do calculations on 'y' and then use x for later purposes. But somehow address of 'y' changes to 'x' even if I assign it initially other than 'x'

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(3,3)
y = np.random.rand(3,3)

print 'y',id(y)

y = x
y[1][1] = -y[1][1]

print x[1][1] + y[1][1]  #This needs to be 0.
print 'x',id(x)
print 'y',id(y)
```

In the above code, I need line 9 ('x[1][1] + y[1][1]'), to print 0, but what is giving is 2 times -x[1][1]. What is the reasoning behind this problem and if you could suggest some method to avoid this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: When indexing a numpy array, get in the habit of using `y[1, 1]` instead of `y[1][1]`.  Here they do the same thing, but `y[:][1]` is not the same as `y[:,1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `y=x` copies just the refrence, and **does not create another copy of the array**

You should replace that line with

```
y = x[:]
```

Otherwise changing `x` also changes `y` and vise versa.

However, this method is good only for a regular `list` and not `numpy` arrays. That is possible like this (also more explicit and readable):

```
y = np.copy(x)
```

If you want to check it yourself, you can `print id(y)` and `print id(x)` after that assignment, and see that in your case they are the same, while in a true copy they are different

Comment: This **does not work**. Slicing creates a *view* in `numpy`, and now `x` and `y` share the same underlying buffer. You have to use `.copy`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i've updated the answer to reflect that